# How to call apk font use CSS in android？

Tags: android, css, android-webview

I set the font for webview. Because the font file is too large, it will Impact loading time seriously when putting the font file in server.

So I decide to pack the font file into apk. But I do not know how to call it in css?

Could anyone give me some advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the path in css as like this way

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'android_myface';
   src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/myfont.ttf'); 
}
```

and use it

```
html{
    font-family: 'android_myface', serif;
}
```

Put your myfont.ttf file in your assests folder